# Bilingual domain wildcard SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate, multilingual

I work on a web application with a wildcard cert -- multiple environments all as subdomains of the root domain, works pretty well.

The application is bilingual (english/french), and supports switching between the two, but the domain name remains english. Someone asked me about supporting a French domain name recently, and that sent me off into research mode.

There are apparently [internationalized domain names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) and although the punycode domain feels pretty weird, the user experience seems ok. And there are multi-domain SSL certificates, which I guess would work if we weren't already using a wildcard certificate. Can you get a multi-domain wildcard cert so that you could accept requests on `*.cats.ca` and `*.chats.ca` (generic example of a domain name in french and english) or `*.cats.com` and `*.gatos.com` for an english/spanish site in America, where a single website host could respond to requests in SSL for subdomains of both domains?

I tried searching, didn't find much -- and I'm not totally convinced this is the right stack exchange, but most of the SSL cert questions I found were here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certificates that do support multi domain wildcards. For example, [this one issued by Comodo](https://crt.sh/?q=f83100ccfaf070131c817f6593f0f765c019b50a) and [another one issued by Digicert](https://crt.sh/?q=4803d5ef72f25a79787638af2fd403c36713878d). You can probably check with your certificate provider on the availability and cost of such a certificate.

[image: Image showing multi domain wildcards in certificate with SHA1 hash f83100ccfaf070131c817f6593f0f765c019b50a]

[image: Image showing multi domain wildcards in certificate with SHA1 hash 4803d5ef72f25a79787638af2fd403c36713878d]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Anand's answer, **Multi Domain Wildcard SSL** certificates can protect both multiple domains and their unlimited number of sub-domains.

**Domains and Sub-domains it can secure**

[image: Multi Domain Wildcard's Domain and Sub-domain security]

Comodo offers 3 types of Multi domain wildcard certificates.

1. Comodo Multi Domain Wildcard - For Organization validation
2. Comodo Positive Multi-Domain Wildcard - For Domain Validation
3. Comodo UCC (Unified Communication) Wildcard - For Organization validation on Microsoft Exchange and OCS server.

Here's the [deals for Multi Domain Wildcard](http://www.promospro.com/promo-codes-cheap-ssl-security) certificates.